# reduce image file size but keep quality, with samle

Tags: image

I am trying to put an image at a website,
the image has a transparent background and i want it to be in very good quality.

I saved it in .PNG format and in high quality but the problem is that it is really heavy and takes lots of time to load.

how can i show the picture in the same size and quality, with transparent background but with smaller file size to load quickly?

i'm talking about the image in the center of this website, with two cordless drils:

```
http://www.tigertools.co.il
```

Comment: have you tried with a gif? 96KB with a GIF, ~48KB with a JPG (backgrounded but you could use the same color of the site).

Comment: Errr ... you could try using a lower quality of PNG and see if you even notice (you probably won't)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) ([pngquant](http://pngquant.org)) can substantially reduce size of transparent PNGs.

Whether it reduces quality depends on the image. Usually loss is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Dithering to 256 color (optimized palette) and saving as PNG seems to bring down file size to 96KB. This is using IrfanView.

However, not all dithering software handles the semi-opaque pixels near the object boundary correctly.

With regard to the quality loss, it's better to do a double-blind test to get unbiased subjective opinion. Keep in mind that the reduced website loading time will make users happier, which may compensate the hypothetical slight loss in quality.